# Difference between reporting and analysis in datawarehousing

Tags: terminology, data-warehouse

.What is the difference between reporting and analysis in datawarehousing? Both are giving output with drill down(hierarchy) and i am feeling similar in the case of outputs.

Comment: Question might be a bit obscure. Could you explain a bit more. I feel you consider analysis as a separate visualization mechanism (according to the way I understand the question).

Answer (score 1):

They are distinct concepts.

First you analyze, then you report the results of the analysis. One is almost useless without the other.
Analysis extract relevant information, reporting displays the information.

Answer (score 0):

Data-warehouse reporting (or reports of any sort for that matter) stands for an output from the data-warehouse which can be BI dashboards, just row column reports or any sort of visualization of data. All these reports may or may not have drill downs.